# import csv to mysql only between certain rows

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv with a range of info that I need load into different mysql tables is there a away to do that?

Data for table 1 would be at the top of the csv between rows 1 and 10 and would have the data heading in column A and the data in Column B Like this:

### heading, data

### heading, data

The below that would be the data for table 2 which would look like this:

### Heading,heading,heading,heading

### data,data,data,data

### data,data,data,data

### data,data,data,data

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you can use the command line, why not skip PHP, break out the different table data into their own files and use `mysqlimport`?

Comment: You have received multiple answers, did any of them help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know after how many lines you will be wanting to change the table, you could do something like (source php.net):

```
...
$table_one_data = array();
$table_two_data = array();
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++        

        if ($row < 1000) {
            array_push($table_one_data, $data);
        } else {
            array_push($table_two_data, $data);
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
....
```

You could also trigger this through data in the CSV file:

```
    ...
    $table_one_data = array();
    $table_two_data = array();

    $field = 0;
    $trigger = "table2";
    $tableChange = false;

    if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            if ($data[field] == $trigger) {
                tableChange = true;
            }

            if (!$tableChange) {
                array_push($table_one_data, $data);
            } else {
                array_push($table_two_data, $data);
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the data in separate files and then use mysqlimport.

If you are not confident with that then you can use [MySqlWorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). It has CSV import facility.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table, load all the data from the csv into this temporary table and add to your table from there based on a key (line for example) from the temporary table.

Something like this.

Create the temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
(
   line int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   field1 varchar(255),
   field2 varchar(255),
   field3 varchar(255)
);
```

Load the data.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE tmp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@field1, @field2, @field3)
SET field1 = @field1,
    field2 = @field2,
    field3  = @field3;
```

So if you want to insert the data from lines 5 to 10 into the table1.

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM tmp
WHERE line >= 5 AND line <= 10
```

Add the rest of the lines into a different table

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM tmp
WHERE line  > 10
```